# Key mappings in a Visual Studio Code git-bash terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, git-bash

I'm using a git-bash terminal in Visual Studio Code. In a normal git-bash terminal outside Visual Studio code, (Ctrl+k) will clear to end of line. However when I do this in a Visual Studio Code git-bash terminal I get message "Waiting for second key of chord". How can I change behavior to be same as a standard git-bash terminal? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found it right after posting! Just needed to disable

`Terminal > Integrated : Allow Chords`

in the Settings. I didn't see this before & didn't know such a setting existed.

Comment: This saved me from a ton of frustration