# How to disable VS Code chords

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

I'm using VS Code 1.51.11 on Mac OS X.

Inside my integrated terminal I want to use the binding `CMD+K` to trigger the `clear` command to clear the terminal. It works in my regular Terminal.app, but when I do it in VS Code's integrated terminal I receive the message `CMD+K was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...`.

I've done research on how to disable chords in VS Code but found no solution in the official documentation or other blog posts on the internet.

I've also checked my key bindings and CMD+K is mapped to this key binding:

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+k",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.clear",
    "when": "terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
  }
```

Any help in helping me to actually map CMD + K to the desired functionality (clearing the integrated terminal in VS Code) would be awesome!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63526730/836330.

Comment: @Mark grateful for the information, but even after disabling chords in the menu I still have the same problem.

Comment: Remove the leading `-` in your keybinding `-workbench.action.terminal.clear` that disables the command.

Comment: @Mark fantastic, this suggestion worked a treat. If you want you can write out this tip as an official answer to my question and I'll designate it as the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things for you to do.  As reported elsewhere disable this setting (enabled is the default):

`Terminal > Integrated : Allow Chords`

Also, your keybinding

```
{
  "key": "cmd+k",
  "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.clear",
  "when": "terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
}
```

has a `-` before the command.  That serves to remove that keybinding and so regardless of the `Allow Chords` settings, that keybinding would never work.  Remove the `-` to enable the keybinding.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow Mark's instructions but `cmd + k` still doesn't work, you might have this problem:

I had assigned the shortcut `editor.unfold` to `cmd + k cmd + u`. This prevented `cmd + k` to clear the terminal. I had to add a when clause to the shortcut: `editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled`.

**First, follow Mark's instructions.** If it still doesn't work, this might be it:

#### This doesn't work

In my VSC this setting has prevented `cmd + k` to clear the terminal:

```json
{
    "key": "cmd+k cmd+u",
    "command": "editor.unfold"
}
```

#### This works

After adding the when clause `editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled`, I could again use `cmd + k` in the terminal.

```json
{
    "key": "cmd+k cmd+u",
    "command": "editor.unfold",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled"
}
```